# Dynamic Elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As I've been doing for years, I can create dynamic HTML using PHP (which has got information from a database).

So for example, let's say I want to create x  number of links dynamically, my PHP script would end up echoing:

```
<a id=link1 href=>Link 1</a>
<a id=link2 href=>Link 2</a>
//etc....
```

which is fine. However, how do I handle the dynamic nature of these buttons with respect to jQuery code? Let's say I want each link to bring up an alert "Hello World":

```
$('#link1').click(function() {
                 alert("Hello World");
                 return false;
                });
```

would I have to duplicate this code for each dynamically created link using PHP? I of course know that this isn't the correct thing to do, however I'm stuck on what is the best method to use

I appreciate any help

Cheers

Comment: So many excellent answers! I'm strugging to choose one! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any HTML that's coming from the server-side (e.g. PHP or ASP.NET) can be treated just as you would normal static HTML. As far as your browser is concerned, that's not dynamically created.

If we were talking about dynamically created elements on the client (like using Javascript / jQuery to create your links) that'd be a different thing altogether. You'll have to adjust your Javascript to account for that, like maybe using `.delegate()` and `.live()` instead of just using vanilla `.bind()` calls, for example.

---

As for your question regarding targeting multiple elements at once, the semantic way to do that is with classes. So, something like

```
<a href="#" id="link1" class="foo">Linky linky</a>
<a href="#" id="link2" class="foo">Linky linky</a>
<a href="#" id="link3" class="foo">Linky linky</a>
```

can be targeted at once via something like

```
$('a.foo').click(function() {
    alert();
});
```

---

Additionally, if you wanted to stop the link click from following into the actual URL, jQuery makes it easy for you by using this instead of `return false;`:

```
$('a.foo').click(function(e) {
    alert();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

You could also call `e.stopPropagation()` to stop the event from bubbling up to the parent elements if you'd like. Sometimes, I just think that `return false` is too much of functionality overkill.

Comment: I selected this as the answer as the writer went a few steps further :) All other answers were excellent though - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

no, you can assign a class to your links and use that to attach the click function

```
<a class='links' id=link1 href= '#' >Link 1</a>
<a class='links' id=link2 href='#' >Link 2</a>

$('a.links').click(function() {
                 alert("Hello World");
                 return false;
                });
```

Answer (score 2):

If all of the needed ids share the same prefix (here it is `link`) it is no problem. There is a selector for "starts with":

```
// This will select all a-elements where the id starts with "link"
$('a[id^="link"]').click(function(event){
    alert("Hello World");
    return false;
});
```

Look here for further examples: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: Add chat about `class` and I'll upvote you. There are a couple of ways to solve the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class for every link and use the class to bind your event code.

```
$(".DynamicLinks").click(function() {
                  alert("Hello World");
                  return false;
                  });
```